# pm: cannot find swap device, try swapon -a

Tags: swap, hibernate

I've just rebuilt a laptop with xubuntu 18.04. I'm having issues getting hibernation to work, swapfile has been increased to slightly more than the 6GB of memory installed, and seems to be available:

```
swapon -s

Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority 

/swapfile                               file        6655996 1992    -2
```

When I try and hibernate I see the following messages on screen:

```
PM: Cannot find swap device, try swapon -a  
PM: Cannot get swap writer
```

The syslog entries before that seem to suggest hibernation was going  going OK up to then.

```
etc/default/grub contains:  
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Any words of wisdom gratefully received...

Comment: After some more digging I've updated GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=/dev/sda1 resume_offset=2047" and the current complaint is "PM: Swap header not found!". I thought that was covered by the resume_offset=2047? The offset is correct.  

@mike Sorry, I haven't got the hang of formatting stuff yet.

Comment: I'm wondering if I've been wasting my  time with trying to get hibernation working; Shutdown with the "Save session for future logins" seems to have more-or-less the same functionality. Apps that were open are remembered; pages open in Firefox need to refreshed, but the URLs have been remembered...